# Xubuntu Laptop Not Suspending Properly on Lid Close

Tags: xubuntu, suspend, power-management, laptop, xfce

I have a Dell Latitude 5580 laptop running Xubuntu 22.04, and the laptop does not suspend when the lid closes. Based on other research, here's what I've tried so far:

- Made sure the "Suspend" option is chosen for "When laptop lid is closed" in the Power Manager.
- Installed `pm-utils`.
- Ran the following command: `xfconf-query -c xfce4-power-manager -p /xfce4-power-manager/logind-handle-lid-switch -n -t bool -s false`

Interestingly, when I use logind to suspend on lid close, the laptop does suspend properly, but the desktop is frozen when I open the computer back up.

I'm not sure where to go next. I'd appreciate any advice the community can provide. Thanks!

Comment: Check that the laptop's firmware is fully up to date. If it isn't, update it. This often helps power-management problems.